# Javascript to find a certain text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table whose values are displayed from a database but on the 8th row second column it displays a value i.e. 8 which is a Canadian province i.e. 'Ontario' now  i want the name of the province instead of the values. This is what the old site used and therefore, i do not want to change the data in the database as the it is really big in size. I want to use javascript so that it only shows this for the user to read rather than changing the values in the database.

The data is displaed in a table

```
<table>
<tr></tr>
 ...8th row<tr><td></td><td>Value lies here i.e. '8'</td></tr>
</table>
```

Here is how i want it

if the value is "0" it should show "Alberta"

if the value is "1"          British Columbia

if the value is "2"          Manitoba

if the value is "3"          New Brunswick

if the value is "4"          Newfoundland

if the value is "5"          Nova Scotia

if the value is "6"          Northwest Territories

if the value is "7"          Nunavut

if the value is "8"          Ontario

if the value is "9"         Prince Edward Island

if the value is "10"        Quebec

if the value is "11"       Saskatchewan

if the value is "12"   Yukon

"Thanks but the form is on a different page than where it shows the value" It should be using a if else statement that if 8th row second column shows '8' then the value should display as 'Ontario'

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking. The `value` attribute is what's sent with the form, the text inside the `<option>` tags is what's shown to the user. No JavaScript needed.

Comment: Are you showing the data in table as well as in the selectbox?

Comment: i think i understand. You want to convert the select menu into a table?

Comment: well select box is not a problem this is how the data is sotred in the database form using the edit page. but when it shows the page (not in edit mode) it displays the value 8 but i want it to show the names of the provinces

Comment: Basically the select has nothing to do with this question at all.

Comment: Yes the select is on the form but it shows how the values are displayed for different provinces but i have changed the question to better understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like a bad solution, but a simple selector

```
var cell = $('#tableId tr:eq(7) td:eq(1)');
var txt = cell.text();
console.log(txt);
var selectOption = $("#selectId option").eq(parseInt(txt,10))
cell.text(selectOption.text());
```

EDIT:

```
var provs = ["Alberta","British Columbia"...];
var cell = $('#tableId tr:eq(7) td:eq(1)');
var index = parseInt(cell.text());
cell.text(provs[index].text());
```

Comment: thanks but the text is displayed in a table please see the updated question

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to use the [`selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Property/selectedIndex) property of the `select` element like this:

```
selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].innerText;
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TLZTr/)

Comment: thanks but the text is displayed in a table please see the updated question

Answer (score 0):

simple :)

```
$('option:selected').val();
```

Comment: thanks but the text is displayed in a table please see the updated question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use plain Javascript, this will work -

Assuming that the id of your select element is "myselect"

```
var name = document.getElementById('myselect').options[document.getElementById('myselect').selectedIndex].text;
```

This will give you Ontario instead of 8, which is its value. You can then insert this into the  database by whichever method you normally use.

Comment: thanks but the text is displayed in a table please see the updated question

Comment: Thanks but i do not want to change the values of the database